# Prevent table from wrapping

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net, html-table

How do I prevent a table from wrapping when it is inside of an outer table cell?

**Have a look at the simplified example at the bottom of my question.**

My aspx-tablerow:

```
<tr runat="server" id="trButtons">
  <td align="left" colspan="9" valign="top" style="white-space:nowrap"><br />
     <asp:Button ID="btnImeiLookup" OnClick="btnImeiLookupClick" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VG_RMA_LOOKUP" CausesValidation="true"   Text="lookup IMEI" ToolTip="lookup IMEI and check if RMA-Number can be generated" Width="120px"  />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="BtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idRMA")%>' ValidationGroup="VG_RMA_SAVE"  runat="server" CausesValidation="false"  Text="Edit" ToolTip="edit" Width="120px"  />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="BtnAdd" runat="server"   CommandName="Add" CausesValidation="false" Text="Add new" Width="130px"  ToolTip="add new"  />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server"   CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("idRMA")%>' CausesValidation="true" Text="Delete" Width="120px"  ToolTip="delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('do you really want to delete this RMA?')" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<uc4:RmaPrinterView ID="RmaPrinterView1" Visible="true" runat="server" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

RmaPrinterView1 is an ASP.Net Usercontrol:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" style="width:120px; white-space:nowrap" onclick="javascript:$('#TblPrinterView').jqprint();" value="Print" title="Print" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table id="TblPrinterView" style="display:none">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100px;white-space:nowrap">
                    <asp:Label ID="LblRmaNumberDesc" runat="server" Text="RMA-Number:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblRmaNumber" runat="server" Text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblImeiDesc" runat="server" Text="IMEI:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblImei" runat="server" Text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblModelDesc" runat="server" Text="Model:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblModel" runat="server" Text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblSiDpyDesc" runat="server" Text="SI/DPY:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblSiDpy" runat="server" Text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblSymptomCodesDesc" runat="server" Text="Symptoms:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblSymptomCodes" runat="server" Text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the Usercontrol with the inner table is wrapped:

[image]

I know that I should avoid table layout, but I needed a fast working solution ;-)

**EDIT**: a simplified sample that is also wrapping:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <input type="button" value="b1" />&nbsp;
        <input type="button" value="b2" />&nbsp;
        <input type="button" value="b3" />&nbsp;
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap"><input type="button" value="in table" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
     </td>
   </tr>                     
</table>
```

**UPDATE**:
The solution - as Jeroen mentioned - was to make the table an inline element with `style="display: inline"`. The next problem was that I used an ASP.Net UpdatePanel inside the UserControl which is normally rendered as a Div. So the next block-element that causes my table to wrap. I only needed to set the [UpdatePanel's RenderMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.rendermode.aspx) to `Inline` what causes it to be rendered as Span.

Comment: Maybe you can set `style="min-width: ..."`?  It may be hard to know exactly what width to put in, but it may work in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the css `white-space` does not work, you can try to add `nowrap="nowrap"` to your `td`, just like you added `valign="top"`.

Very ugly, but it should work.

**Edit:** Ah, now I see: A table is a block-level element so it will always go to a new line unless you make it an inline-element or float it.

Comment: Thank you, but this also does not work. Neither when addding it to the outer table's cell nor when adding it to the inner table's cell. I have added a simplified example of the problem to the end of my question.

Comment: Thank you, making it an inline element worked. `<table style="display:inline">`

Answer (score 1):

```
table tr td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but as Jeroen has mentioned, i'd already added that to the style of the cell and it does not work. I have added a simplified example of the problem to the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You've put the table at odds with itself. It is set to finite pixel count and yet you don't want to wrap once that's exceeded. You might attempt:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Thank you, but only Jeroen's tip to make it an inline element worked. `<table style="display:inline">`