# Fill an html table by column instead of row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
'<table> 
    <tr>
        <th>' .$varProduct[$x][0].  '</th>'.  //this is a title
       '<th>' .$varProduct[$x][2] . $varProduct[$x][11] . ' </th> // this is a price
    </tr>
</table>'
```

This code makes a table that fills out like this:

```
Title Price
Title Price
Title Price
```

but I want to fill it

```
Title Title Title
Price Price Price
```

Can I do this with some library or CSS stylings I know this isn't how the DOM normally aligns elements.

okay now it's going like this

```
Title Title Title Title   //uses up the whole page so goes to next linke
Title Price Price PRice 
PRice
```

I would like it to go

```
Title Title Title TItle
PRice PRice PRice PRice
Title 
PRice
```

Comment: if you have  access to the source code of HTML, why don't you change it the way you want it to be ?

Comment: **Loop over your column headers first**, then do another loop over your data outputting the contents into each row.

Comment: Is the code snippet php?

Comment: [Check out this example](https://jsfiddle.net/weabfxbn/) please. All you need to do is to generate this table structure dynamically and pay attention to what @scunliffe suggested.

Comment: yeah I should thought of that before to use two loops it's more simplified too. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer and fiddle. Did I understand you correctly ?

Comment: I see what you mean. You may want to check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378829/prevent-table-from-wrapping)

Comment: You have your answer below, but ask yourself if this is really a table or tabular data or is it a **list** of products? A well styled list may help you here and provide better flexibility when it comes to responsiveness.

Comment: yeah but On the client's side they can't tell the difference it looks the same.  the border would be hidden either way this actually achieves the same affect with less css and html tags

Comment: Less CSS yes, less html tags, no.... but anyway way here is a quick, dirty and more flexible list example.... just in case: http://jsfiddle.net/ej09p9o7/1/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weabfxbn/1/) accordingly but using JS. It should give you an idea.

HTML

```
<div id="dynamic">

</div>
```

JS

```
var priceList = [ 'price1', 'price2', 'price3'];
var itemList = [ 'item1', 'item2', 'item3' ];

$('#dynamic').append('<table><caption>DYNAMIC</caption><tr>');   
for (var i=0; i<3; i++){

    $('#dynamic').append('<td>' + itemList[i] + '</td>');
}
$('#dynamic').append('</tr><tr>');

for (var i=0; i<3; i++){

    $('#dynamic').append('<td>' + priceList[i] + '</td>');
}
$('#dynamic').append('</tr></table>');
```

**UPDATE**

**Updated Output**

```
DYNAMIC
item1   item2   item3   item4
price1  price2  price3
```

Check out [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weabfxbn/2/) please

Comment: I can't scale this though... if I have more than 4 items the first for loop goes to the next line break  and pushes the 2nd for loop down

Comment: well, then you can have empty cells, right ? Isn't that OK ? Lemme update the fiddle.

Comment: I edited it. Do you get what I mean? the for loop is making the items go to the next line before it reaches the for loop to fill with my 2nd for loop of prices

Comment: I think that may have been why i tried to use a single for loop

Comment: CAn I do like maybe a nested loop and  for ever 4th item let the other loop run or something?

Comment: if you add 100 items tho how to do you skip down??.. in your fiddle the dynamic will always have 2 rows won't it??

Comment: It is just a simple example to show you how it is done. I bet you do NOT keep your data in a 2 separate 1 dimensional array, do you ? Just iterate through your data and decorate your table similarly.

Comment: I got around it by putting each for loop in one bigger for loop nested. the first checks   for($i =0; $i < count($varProduct)/4; $i++ ) then each for loop inside for($x =0; $x < 4; $x++ ) echo  $varProduct[$i+$x][0] it's not actually increasing hte big o notation either 4 is how many spaces on my page before the line breaks

Comment: Yep, you are moving in the right direction. =] I have just noticed that you are using hard coded indexes for boundary checking in your loops. Try to use blah.length. That way, in case, the number of items in your list changes, you wouldn't need to update your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81220/discussion-between-alp-and-ryan-williams).

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want a table with just two rows. The top row contains the titles of the products and the bottom row contains the prices.
As @scunliffe said loop over the  titles then the prices.

```
print "<table><tr>";

foreach ($varProduct as $value){
    print  "<td>".$value[0]."</td>";
}

print '</tr><tr>';

foreach ($varProduct as $value){
    print  "<td>".$value[2].$value[11]."</td>";
}

print "</td></table>";
```