# Javascript put data in columns table

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, laravel

I have a table which I want to put in the data that I get from ajax call in columns instead of rows here is the table body code

```
<tbody id="tableData-marketMonth">
    <tr>
        <th>Leads</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Full Year Cost</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>{{date('F')}} Share of Cost</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Cost per Lead</th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the JavaScript code that put the data into the table

```
//Monthly Marketing Cost Report
$.get('/dashboard/costs', function(data){
  $.each(data,function(i,value){
    var tr =$("<tr/>");

    tr.append($("<th/>",{
      text : value.olxTotal
    })).append($("<th/>",{
      text : value.budget_total_year
    })).append($("<th/>",{
      text : value.budget_total_month
    })).append($("<th/>",{
      text : value.budget_per_lead
    }))
    $('#tableData-marketMonth').append(tr);
  })  
})
```

this is the current output
[image: Current]
  Desired output
  [image: Desired]

Thank you very much

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989927/fill-an-html-table-by-column-instead-of-row

Comment: thank you for your answer i tried it but i didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and I think I understood what you meant, probably best just to add id's to each `<tr>` and then append the value to them, like below.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody id="tableData-marketMonth">
        <tr id="leads">
            <th>Leads</th>
         </tr>
         <tr id="fyc">
             <th>Full Year Cost</th>
         </tr>
         <tr id="soc">
             <th>{{date('F')}} Share of Cost</th>
         </tr>
         <tr id="cpl">
             <th>Cost per Lead</th>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery

```
//Monthly Marketing Cost Report
$.get('/dashboard/costs', function(data){
  $.each(data,function(i,value){
      var leads = $('#leads');
      var budget_total_year = $('#fyc');
      var budget_total_month = $('#soc');
      var budget_per_lead = $('#cpl');

      leads.append('<td>' + value.olxTotal + '</td>');
      budget_total_year.append('<td>' + value.budget_total_year + '</td>');
      budget_total_month.append('<td>' + value.budget_total_month + '</td>');
      budget_per_lead.append('<td>' + value.budget_per_lead + '</td>');
  })  
})
```

Comment: Amazing thank you very much works like a charm  
Exactly what i wanted to do

Comment: awesome! this isn't the cleanest code ever, feel free to clean it up, i like having examples that people can see what's happening and learn from it :)